# Coin3D library using cmake on Fedora 20 - fatal error: Inventor/Qt/SoQt.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, fedora20, coin3d

I have create a project that uses Cmake and Coin3D libraries: https://github.com/tuxdna/phyloviz

I am getting a `fatal error: Inventor/Qt/SoQt.h: No such file or directory`. This is what I am doing:

```
$ sudo yum install cmake SoQt-devel
$ cd path/to/phyloviz
[phyloviz] $ mkdir build
[phyloviz] $ cd build/
[phyloviz/build] $ cmake ../ -DCOIN3D_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/Coin2/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found PkgConfig: /bin/pkg-config (found version "0.28") 
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt4: /bin/qmake-qt4 (found version "4.8.5") 
-- Found Coin3D: /usr/lib64/libCoin.so  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: .../phyloviz/build
```

Now lets compile the code

```
[phyloviz/build] $ make
Scanning dependencies of target ev-iv
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/ev-iv.dir/src/ev-iv/ev-iv.cc.o
.../phyloviz/src/ev-iv/ev-iv.cc:1:30: fatal error: Inventor/Qt/SoQt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Inventor/Qt/SoQt.h>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ev-iv.dir/src/ev-iv/ev-iv.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ev-iv.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[phyloviz/build]$
```

Even though I have specified the include directory using `cmake ../ -DCOIN3D_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/Coin2/`, I am getting the `fatal error` above.

This works fine on Ubuntu 14.04. How can I resolve this?